# Prolog: store solutions in a list

Tags: list, prolog, store

This is a very simple question ;)

---

fact(a).

fact(b).

test(X):-fact(X).

---

the solutions are X=a; X=b. OK

I'm trying to create:  test(X,L):-fact(X), ???  that returns L=[a,b]

can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findall/3` to [aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) solutions:

```
test(L):-
  findall(X, fact(X), L).
```

Comment: The `X` in the predicate `test` is superfluous.

Comment: @mbratch: right, i'd say it was just plain wrong ;). Fixed it